# Java Script of autosearch is not working on textbox with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, autocomplete

I want a text box with auto search JavaScript. My Aspx textbox is:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_DestinationRoute" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="e.g. Route you followed" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="destinations" ID="rfvtxt_DestinationRoute" ControlToValidate="txt_DestinationRoute" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

My JavaScript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txt_DestinationRoute'));
            google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
                var place = places.getPlace();
                var address = place.formatted_address;
                var latitude = place.geometry.location.A;
                var longitude = place.geometry.location.F;
                var mesg = "Address: " + address;
                mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
                mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
                //document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = latitude;
                //document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = longitude;
                alert(mesg);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**It works fine when I try it with normal text box without any CSS class**
but it won't work with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is asp generates different id for client side, try :

```
<asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static"
```

Also look at your generated textbox in code inspector.

Other wise you can try this:

```
   var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('<%= txt_DestinationRoute.ClientID %>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below answer

UI

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
    <input id="birds" size="50" />
    <input type="button" id="search-trigger" value="Trigger" />
</div>


  **Script**

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    // Button listener that triggs the search event
    $("#search-trigger").click(function(){
        var searchTerm = $( "#birds" ).val();
        $( "#birds" ).autocomplete( "search" , searchTerm);
    });


    $( "#birds" )               
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            source: ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"], 
                /* Commented this out to use dummy data above
                            function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON( "search.php", {
                    term: extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );
            },*/
            search: function() {
                var term = extractLast( this.value );

                          /* What is this check for?
                if ( term.length < 2 ) {


 return false;
                }*/
            },
            focus: function() {
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                terms.pop();
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
            },
            //Added for "show all" support
            minLength: 0
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I had issue with textbox css not with script.... but thank for new approch it is also good way..

Comment: Thankz for your feedback :)